# Scope of variables with a function within a function?

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

In Python you can have the following:

```
def foo(param1, param2):
    def bar():
        print param1 + param2
    bar()
```

I am having some difficulties with this behaviour in PHP though.
I expect this to work in the following way:

```
function foo($param1, $param2)
{
    function bar()
    {
        echo $param1 + $param2;
    }
    bar();
}
```

But that fails. So I read some about closures (this is called a closure is it not? It is in Python, that I know). And in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) about anonymous functions (which they said to have been implemented as closures) they tell you to use the use() expression in the following manner:

```
function foo($param1, $param2)
{
    function bar() use($param1, $param2)
    {
        echo $param1 + $param2;
    }
    bar();
}
```

But that still fails. So I changed it to the PHP-anonymous function a-like like this:

```
function foo($param1, $param2)
{
    $bar = function() use($param1, $param2)
    {
        echo $param1 + $param2;
    };
    $bar();
}
```

That does work, however it just looks really ugly. Am I missing something? Can I improve this in any way? Or will I just have to use the 'ugly' way?

(I am not looking for a discussion about if closures are useful)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find the `function bar() use($param1, $param2)` syntax on the manual page you linked to, just the "ugly" version that works (which is truly *anonymous*). I guess you'll have to use that.

On your second example, `bar` is not a closure. To create a closure in PHP you have to use the ugly `use`, or the [`Closure` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php). Every function will create its own local scope, but closures are not automatic.

PHP seems to have an odd definition for the term "closure", as you probably noted when you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). They define it as a synonym for "anonymous function":

> Anonymous functions, also known as *closures* (...)

Confusing, right? Later, they explain you need the `use` keyword if you want to inherit the parent scope:

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be declared in the function header.

The [PHP Wiki rfc page on closures](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures#common_misconceptions) gives us some hints on why closures were implemented this way:

> PHP's notion of scope is quite different than the notion of scope other languages define. Combine this with variable variables ($$var) and it becomes clear that automatically detecting which variables from the outer scope are referenced inside are closure is impossible. Also, since for example global variables are not visible inside functions either by default, automatically making the parent scope available would break with the current language concept PHP follows.

Comment: I couldn't find that syntax as well I just assumed it being missing from the doc pages when I was looking for a solution a week ago :-)

Comment: The thing is, the page is about anonymous functions, but that function is not anonymous, it has a name (`bar`).

Comment: Yeah I know it is about anonymous functions, but in my vocabulary a closure is a function/method within another function/method. Searching for PHP closures only lists that page as a valid page about closures. Event PHP states that them anonymous functions are made with closures.

Comment: @ your edit, exactly it is confusing. There are functions/methods, anonymous functions, closures and lambda's. But they all 'should' be different. In my programming-vocabulary that is.

Comment: @Daan I totally agree. But that shouldn't surprise us, since it's PHP (sigh).

Comment: @Daan, It seems that automatically allowing anonymous functions to access the parent scope would break other stuff in PHP, and that's why it requires `use`. See my latest edit.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you can't access intermediate scopes. You only have your local scope, and the global scope. This is an artefact of the perverse scope rules of PHP, which are the complete opposite of any sane language's scope rules.

Comment: So I am stuck with the latter solution?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, a named function declaration (`function bar ()`) declares a function in the global scope. So in your first example, when you run your `foo` function, it will define a `bar` function in the global scope, and then *everybody* can access the `bar` function as if you declared it outside of `foo`. Functions and variables are separate in PHP. There is just one scope for named functions: global; whereas you have local variables, there is no such thing as locally-scoped functions.

In other words, putting it inside of `foo` is an illusion; named function declaration always declares it globally; putting it inside `foo` simply delays the time when the declaration is run (thus delaying when it is defined) to the execution of `foo`.

A closure is what you need. Other answers have showed you how to do that.

Comment: darn you! There me was thinking that I wasn't polluting the global namespace when using closures! learning something new everyday, thanks for that bit of information!

Comment: @DaanTimmer: You are not polluting the global namespace when using closures. But `bar` is not a closure (it cannot close over local variables, as you found out). Only anonymous functions are closures in PHP.

Comment: I am still calling the first bar a closure :P But that is just how I know it. But indeed. What would be the official name for the first bar? Any clue?

Comment: @DaanTimmer: I would say, nested function